# How do I link data on Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First I don't know what a good title for this question

Example [image]

On `postid` and `wordid` I can click and it will go to another table.

I want to know what code to make data in phpmyadmin can be click and link to related table?

Comment: Are you looking for the source code in the phpmyadmin codebase that makes those links?  It's pretty simple to make a hyperlink that links to a related table.

Comment: i think its in config `$cfg['Servers'[$i]['relation']`

Comment: If that are foreign keys, and you're going to do this just for a easier way to navigate there, it's a pity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that are just foreign keys and will let you know which table has this key so that it will be easy for end user (developer) to know yes this field has the relationship with this field of this table.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use innoDB, you'll have to use the database designer tool in phpmyadmin to set the relations between your tables. After that, you will be able to click on foreign keys as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please show other table views. postid looks like the Primary key and wordid comes from another table.

This is a basic sql join here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29